# Fill missing values between between anchor points

Tags: pandas, dataframe, missing-data, fill

I have a dataframe with a column that indicates the first minute and the 45th minute that is played for a couple of games. The timestamps inbetween are missing. I would like to fill these missing values with the respective timestamp. The dataframe looks like this

```
Group   Index   MatchMin
0       0       nan
0       1       nan
0       2       1
0       3       nan
0       4       nan
0       5       nan
...
0       48      45 
0       49      nan
0       50      nan
1       0       nan
1       1       nan
1       2       1
1       3       nan
1       4       nan
1       5       nan
...
1       48      45 
1       49      nan
1       50      nan
...
```

The desired output should be:

```
Group   Index   MatchMin
0       0       nan
0       1       nan
0       2       1
0       3       2
0       4       3
0       4       4
...
0       48      45 
0       49      nan
0       50      nan
1       0       nan
1       1       nan
1       2       1
1       3       2
1       4       3
1       5       4  
...
1       48      45 
1       49      nan
1       50      nan
...
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If solution should be simplify by interpolate per groups but only between first and last non mising values is possible use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`Series.interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html):

```
f = lambda x: x.interpolate(limit_area='inside')
df['MatchMin'] = df.groupby('Group')['MatchMin'].transform(f)
```

Comment: Unfortunaley, this does not work (nothing happens). 
But thank you, anyway!